# What does 'helping handis' mean?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

It's the name of an American Dad episode i.e. Helping Handis. Stan tries to help Steve to become more masculine by injecting him with some hormones, but instead Steve grows boobies.

Is handis the same as in 'handi-capped' i.e. Stan's efforts were hindered or it has another connotation?

Comment: It's all a matter of opinion. If you see a pun on *handicapped* as well as *hands*, that's up to you, but this doesn't imply ***handi** = handicapped* any more than the Family Guy episode [*Tears of a Clooney*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0796020/) implies ***Clooney** = clown*.

Comment: What?! Are you trying to say that I'm so stupid that I would think that Clooney means a clown? You are good at criticizing, but can't offer an explanation.

Comment: I don't recall this specific episode, but presumably *you* have watched it, and can confirm @DSKekaha's assertion that it features the "Handicapped Mafia". You should also be able to establish using any dictionary that ***handi(s)*** is neither an English word nor a productive prefix, so all you can be asking here is *What does this one-off usage allude to?* To which the answer can only be *Whatever you think fit [taking context into account]*.

Comment: How can you comment on something that you haven't watched or remember? Please refrain from further comments, they are not helpful and you sound angry. Thanks

Comment: I don't wish to be rude or cause offence. My comments here are intended to justify my closevote (I don't think this question is a suitable one for ELU, because it's either Primarily Opinion-based or a form of "Lit Crit", depending on how you see it).

Comment: If I assume your premise that this could mean anything then it means the creators of the episode named it without thinking, whatever first thing came to their mind, but it is logical to assume that there is a reason behind it and that's what we are trying to find out. You are not helpful at all and the wrong person to monitor questions as your logic is flawed. It is not opinion based, it is used in this particular context. If it was opinion based I would just ask the question without providing any further context, but there is a context within which there is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: And English language is not just English that you find in dictionaries, it is also slang or some less known or even not recorded idioms, so not everything can be answered by simply looking it up in a reference guide or googling and that is why stackexchange exists specifically for questions like this.

Comment: I'm not angry. (Perhaps I should have used a few smileys! :) I would like you (and/or 4 other users with closevote privileges and/or a site moderator) to agree with my position so the question can be closed as Off Topic. But if that doesn't happen - well, I've made my point, and it's really up to the community at large to decide whether the question should remain open or not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Of course it wasn't just *my* assertion. I provided a link which documents the events in the episode, including the Handicapped Mafia arc.

Comment: @MarinaDunst I think FF has missed the point of the *Family Guy* references (which is a credit to him).  They're puns.  As DSK notes below In one subplot of "Helping Handis," Francine helps a criminal gang of handicapped characters.  And in "Tears of a Clooney," George Clooney is portrayed as an untalented narcissist whom Francine hates.  But nothing FF writes warrants the conclusion that he's calling you stupid.  There's plenty of hostility and condescension here, but it's usually overt.  No need to read anything dire into an opinion about jokey references in a cartoon.

Comment: @deadrat: Oh Lordie! It's come to something when I can be credited with brownie points for *not* watching/remembering everything in Family Guy! For the record, I *do* watch it - and some of their neologistic puns *(What does **to stir the paint** mean?)* crack me up, even if they're sometimes *exceptionally* coarse.

Comment: @FumbleFingers OK, then, no brownie points for you.  Especially if you don't know what "stir the paint" means. I just wanted to encourage Marina Dunst to stop regarding a contrary opinion as a personal attack.  For instance, I think "Lordy" is preferred.

Comment: @deadrat: They learned me English on the plantation, where we wasn't let do no reading and riting 'lessun we might start getting uppity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry to hear it.  I have forwarded your name to the Freedmen's Bureau.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is referring to handicapped persons.  If you recall, in that same episode Francine starts working for the Handicapped Mafia.

http://americandad.wikia.com/wiki/Helping_Handis

Comment: Ah maybe that's what it is.

Comment: I know the answer! It is a double entendre! Stan trying to help Steve which is helping hands and Francine helping handis i.e. helping handicapped mafia. Handis is used as a diminutive form of handicapped.

Comment: @MarinaDunst If my answer helped you to figure out the answer to your question or helped you gain a better understanding, it might be appropriate to upvote it, and then accept as soon as practicable  :)

Comment: First let's see if there are some uptight people who want to close the question, if it stays open I will def accept it. It turned out to be a perfectly valid question even it didn't seem at the beginning. It is a double entendre, and it is about a new, diminutive form for handicapped i.e. new usages in the English language. I would be really surprised if people thought it didn't belong here or was off topic.